# Is it possible to have multiple account structures with EveryAuth / MongooseAuth?

Tags: authentication, node.js, express, mongoose, everyauth

I'm working on setting up authentication with connect-auth on express & mongoose but there is just so much to do and it's kind of bogging me down. I could continue down this path but it seems like a lot like re-inventing the wheel.

EveryAuth (with MongooseAuth helper) looks rather appealing but the main reason I didn't go with it initially is that I have several account types with their own properties and workflows. For example, some account types require approval while others can login with oauth/openid without approval.

From looking over the examples, it looks like it is pretty opinionated over the general flow. I just don't know how difficult it would be or if it's even possible to step outside of the normal account auth approach.

Is it possible to have EveryAuth settings for each model type? If not, is there any other way to handle different workflows?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customize `findOrCreateUser` in EveryAuth for each strategy ie: facebook, github